# Is it possible to export PowerPoint shape in custom format and then import it back to powerpoint?

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

Have a wierd request.
I have a powerpoint add-in which allows to quickly insert shapes and graphics (also shapes) to the presentation.
It works ok, but the obvious problem I see now is performance, as I store shapes in seperate pptx file.
There are 2 ways I approached working with the shape insertion:
1. Store everything in one presentation and keep it open in the background. The downside is that it makes powerpoint really slow, because the file is just too big (more than 8 mb)
2. Store every slide as a seperate file and open it as needed. This just makes the programm slower, than usual, but works fine. The key downside is that PowerPoint stores every open file in the register and you can not use "recent file" features of the PPT.

What I hoped was possible to do is to save each shape from powerpoint that I heed as seperate file and insert them individually, which would significantly increase the speed of my add-in. However, the only thing I could do is just expoer shape as EMF, which is unacceptable for me.

So my question is: is it possible to export PowerPoint shape in custom format and then import it back to powerpoint? I am using VB.net and VS 2013
Team foundation addin for VS 2013 does something similar, but I need to understant the code and logic behind it and have no idea for now.

You help is HIGHLY appreciated.
Iakov

Comment: What code are you using to open the separate files?  I do something similar with a couple of my VBA add-ins and don't see the files showing up in the Most Recently Used (MRU) list.

Comment: Steve, thanks for your reply. I am using vb.net. To get the shape/slide i would have to open the presentation first. Something like: Globals.thisaddin.application.activepresentation.InsertFromFile(filename). After this action if I right click on the ppt application in the windows bar, where it is pinned I see the "filename" I used

Comment: So you're inserting slides into the current presentation?  Instead, try opening the external presentation windowlessly, then copy the graphic, paste it where you want it, then close the windowless presentation.